# How to login into a network switch using ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, console, serial-port

I have a network switch which is connected to my Ubuntu Desktop through Ethernet port.

I would like to login into the network switch and execute some commands. Can I use Minicom or is there any other way?

I found Ethernet to serial converters online. But is it not possible to setup serial communication using a plain ethernet cable?

Comment: Which network switch are you trying to log into?  As far as I know, you need Serial to Ethernet for Console ports.  But you can use plain Ethernet for NetMgt (Net Management).  With a Console port you don't need to know the IP, where with NetMgt you would need to know the IP.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks. I am using extreme networks x440 switch.
http://extremenetworks.com/product/x440-series/

I have connected the console port of the switch to ethernet port of my desktop.  I don't have the ip address, so is there no way other than buying the converter?

Comment: Summit X440-8t
• 8 x 10/100/1000BASE-T (RJ45) ports
• 4 x 100/1000BASE-X (SFP) unpopulated ports
• 2 x SummitStack
• 1 x Serial (console port) and 1 x 10/100BASE-T out-of-band management port

Comment: For the Console port you will need a Serial to Ethernet cable.  Once you can get into the switch, you can then set the `10/100BASE-T out-of-band management port` to the IP of your choice for direct ssh connectivity to it.

Comment: Even in the [manual](http://extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/summitpubsv1.pdf) I can't seen anything about a default IP address for it.  So, from my experience with smart switches you would need a Console connection (Serial to Ethernet) to configure it with first.

Comment: @Terrance can you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done.  I can remove my comments from here if you like. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some of the specifications of the Summit X440 series switches I can see both console and net management ports:

Summit X440-8t

- 8 x 10/100/1000BASE-T (RJ45) ports
- 4 x 100/1000BASE-X (SFP) unpopulated ports
- 2 x SummitStack
- 1 x Serial (console port)
- 1 x 10/100BASE-T out-of-band management port

The last port listed is the net management port, but even in the [manual](http://extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/summitpubsv1.pdf) I cannot see a default IP address listed.  So, from my experience, to configure this switch to allow connection to the net management port for straight Ethernet you would need to connect a console connection (Serial to Ethernet) cable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have connected ethernet to management port and will try some standard ethernet addresses that could be assigned by dhcp(192.168.2.xx). I am using telnet.. I will come back if some help needed.